# Is there a way to do nested generate statements in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

I am trying to reduce some code by using generate statements, but I can only figure out how to do via nesting, but I don't believe that that is allowed.

What I have is essentially some for-loops running (which require a generate), and within them I want to run one of three sections of code depending on a value that is set when the code is built (which then requires a second generate).  Is there a way to do this and make the tools happy?

Here is a quick-and-dirt picture of what I am trying:

```
    //TAPS_PER_CHAN is a value defined when the code is built
genvar srcNode, dstNode, tapIdx;
 generate
  for (dstNode=0; dstNode<NODES; dstNode=dstNode+1)
    begin: dstForLoop
    generate
        if(TAPS_PER_CHAN <= 4)
        begin
            call module one
        end    
        else if (TAPS_PER_CHAN <= 8)
        begin
            call module two
        end      
       else if (TAPS_PER_CHAN <= 16)
       begin  
            call module three
        end
    endgenerate
    end
endgenerate
```

Comment: what does "value defined when the code is built" mean? is it a parameter? a localparam? a define?

Comment: It is a paramter passed into the module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, simply remove then nested `generate`/`endgenerate` keywords. 
See [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 27 *Generate constructs*.

```
    //TAPS_PER_CHAN is a value defined when the code is built
genvar srcNode, dstNode, tapIdx;
 generate
  for (dstNode=0; dstNode<NODES; dstNode=dstNode+1)
    begin: dstForLoop
    // generate <-- remove this
        if(TAPS_PER_CHAN <= 4)
        begin
            call module one
        end    
        else if (TAPS_PER_CHAN <= 8)
        begin
            call module two
        end      
       else if (TAPS_PER_CHAN <= 16)
       begin  
            call module three
        end
    // endgenerate <-- remove this
    end
endgenerate
```

example [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2qy)

Comment: The problem I had with this approach is that it seems to instantiate all three modules.  What I was hoping to have happen is just the 1 modules needed gets added in, saving space/resources. TAPS_PER_CHAN is a parameter passed into this module (if that makes a difference).

Comment: Nope, the used module is controlled by `TAPS_PER_CHAN` while the number of instances is controlled by `NODES`. See the example: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2qy

Answer (score 0):

Once is in Generate block, Verilog compiler/simulator automatic identify variable (if-else, for-loop) vs Parameter+gen_var(if-else, for-loop)
So, if you define  TAP_PER_CHAN as parameter, you don't need second generate, and verilog/simulator will generate only one of three modules:

It works and identify correct construct in my NC-Verilog, Ascent-Lint, and Novas-nTrace.

parameter TAP_PER_CHAN;
genvar srcNode, dstNode, tapIdx;
 generate
  for (dstNode=0; dstNode
        else if (TAPS_PER_CHAN <= 8)
        begin
            call module two
        end
       else if (TAPS_PER_CHAN <= 16)
       begin
            call module three
        end
    // endgenerate <-- remove this
    end
endgenerate